# Number of arrangements with $n$ things separating $2$ things

Tags: combinatorics

> The word circle has $2$ C's in it. Let's say we want to find how many arrangements can be made of all the letters if we want to have AT LEAST $2$ letters to separate the C's. Then, how many arrangements can be made under these constraints?

My thought process was as follows:

We start with counting the number of arrangements for at least $1$ letter of separation:

_ I _ R _ L _ E _ where we have $4!$ for the arrangements of I,R,L, and E, and for each space we add $1$ C. We pick 2 of the 5 spaces to get $\binom52.$ Put together we get:
$$4!\cdot\binom52= 4!\cdot10 = 240$$

And then we have to subtract off all the instances of only $1$ letter of separation and that should give us the number of arrangements for at least $2$ letters. For exactly $1$ letter of separation we should have the following setup:

_ I _, _ R _, _ L _, or _ E _. Where we have to pick $1$ of the $4$ letters to separate the $2$ C's and then for that letter we choose only the $2$ spaces next to it so it should be $\binom22$ from there. So, we should get:$$4!\binom41\cdot \binom22= 4!\cdot 4 = 96$$

And we subtract that from the number of arrangements for at least $1$ letter to get: $240-96 = 144$

I have a feeling I might have screwed something up here as I made up the question from another one and don't have an answer key or anything like that. Could someone please verify?

Comment: For `m Choose n` , you can use, for example, `\binom{m}{n}` to obtain $\binom{m}n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution looks fine to me.

Another very similar approach:

- There are $6!/2$ total permutations.
- There are $5!$ permutations where the two Cs are adjacent.
- There are $4! \cdot 4$ permutations where there is exactly one letter separating the two Cs.

$$6!/2 - 5! - 4! \cdot 4 = 360 - 120 - 96 = 144$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the 5 letters $CIRLE$, we have 5!=120 ways to organize these 5 letters. We want to add a new letter $C_1$, $C_1$ should be after $C$ , with at least 2 letters between $C$ and $C_1$.
In the 120 solutions for 5 letters $CIRLE$ :

- $C$ is in $1^{st}$ place 24 times, and in this case, we have 3 positions for $C_1$
- $C$ is in $2^{nd}$ place 24 times, and we have 2 positions for $C_1$
- $C$ is in $3^{rd}$ place 24 times, and we have 1 position for $C_1$
- $C$ is in $4^{th}$ or $5^{th}$ place 24+24 times, and we have no valid position for $C_1$

Total is $ 24 \times (3+2+1)=144 $

All methods confirm your result.

Answer (score 0):

Number of letters in the word CIRCLE is $6$. We just need to find the location of two $C$s.

If first letter is $C$ then we want next $C$ to be in one of locations $4,5,6$.
This has $3 \times 4!$ possible arrangments.

Similarly when first appearance of $C$ is second letter, we have $2 \times 4!$ possible arrangements.

Similarly when first appearance of $C$ is third letter, we have $1 \times 4!$ possible arrangements.

Similarly when first appearance of $C$ is fourth letter, we have $0 \times 4!$ possible arrangements.

So overall: we have, $3 \times 4! + 2 \times 4! + 1 \times 4! + 0 \times 4!$ arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

Hi: Refer to the positions as 1,2,3,4,5 and 6.  _ _ _ _ _ _

Then, to make sure the 2 c's are seperated by atleast 2 positions,
you can have: ( notice you when you have an arrangement for the 2c's, you need to multiply by 4 factorial because that's the number of ways of putting the other four letters)

2 c's in 1 and  4    times ( 4 * 3 * 2 * 1)

2 c's in 1 and  5    times ( 4 * 3 * 2 * 1)

2 c's in 1 and  6    times ( 4 * 3 * 2 * 1)

2 c's in 2 and 5     times ( 4 * 3 * 2 * 1)

2 c's in 2 and 6     times ( 4 * 3 * 2 * 1)

2 c's in 3 and 6     times ( 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 )

So, 6 times 24 = 144. So, we got the same answer which tells me that we are probably correct.